# In VS Code, I can't get debugging to work with LiveServer and Firefox / Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox

Using [Debugger For Firefox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug) in VS Code, and running an instance of [LiveServer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) for my HTML/JS application on localhost, breakpoints do not work when opening the site in Firefox or Firefox Developer Edition.

VS code has generated the `launch.json` for debugging in Firefox for my project, with the relevant part here:

```
{
    "name": "Launch localhost",
    "type": "firefox",
    "request": "launch",
    "reAttach": true,
    "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

The issue is that when I then run this setup, Firefox cannot find the page, and even if it does, breakpoints do not work. The equivalent of the above for Chrome works, however.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by changing the settings on LiveServer so that it always works on localhost port 8080, it won't just chose a random port when its active. This can be done by adding the following to LiveServer's settings.json file:

```
"liveServer.settings.port": 8080,
```

In the launch.json code included in the above question, the following line is causing the issue:

```
"url": "http://localhost/index.html",
```

This should instead be

```
"url": "http://localhost:8080",
```

Once this change is made, and all the Firefox configurations suggested under 'Attach' on [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug) are made and LiveServer is active for your project, the debugger should work for Firefox.